# How to install JMX plugin and Jconsole plugin in netbeans 20

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I would like to monitor java applications from netbeans using JMX plugin and Jconsole plugin.

I'm going through the below tutorial -

https://netbeans.apache.org/tutorial/main/kb/docs/java/jmx-getstart/#_accessing_the_jmx_wizards

It recommends ***JMX plugin*** and ***JConsole plugin*** are needed and those are available in the ***NetBeans Update Center***

I have gone through the netbeans plugins portal https://plugins.netbeans.apache.org/ but I couldn't find such plugins available in those site.

I've also checked in the ***Available Plugins*** tabs in **Tools** -> **Plugins**

[image: netbeans plugins installer]

Any idea how can I install those plugins in netbeans 20?